# Tomcat OpenEJB and CDI

Tags: tomcat, cdi, openejb

I am using OpenEJB 3.1 embedded in Tomcat6.33 for testing our EJBs. Now I am trying to use CDI in EJB. I have done the settings for using CDI in Tomcat so now I can use @Inject in my Servlet and everything works fine.

However when I try to use @Inject in my EJB it fails with Null Pointer (because the object was not injected). How can I used CDI in my embedded OpenEJB inside Tomcat?

Regards

Comment: CDI support was added in OpenEJB 4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hard to tell from the information you provide. Did you deploy an beans.xml in the relevant projects? Try querying the beanmanager for what is around. Are your OpenEJB components recognized as ManagedBeans?

Comment: Yes, I have got my beans.xml in the project. I tried to query Bean Manager, but even BeanManager is not getting injected. How can i check if my OpenEJB components are recognized as ManagedBeans?

Comment: No BeanManager - this smells like a problem with your setup... I would be to register a small extension that dumps everything you have right after @BeanDiscovery. You can get the BeanManager injected right into the observer-method.

Comment: This setup works fine with TomEE plus profile. But i was trying if by any way we can bootstrap it with earlier versions, so that we don't force others to upgrade.